# Uploading video to Firebase Storage Error Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, video, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a video to Firebase Storage but I am getting the following error...

```
*** Assertion failure in -[FIRStorageUploadTask enqueue], /Users/.../Documents/.../.../Pods/FirebaseStorage/Firebase/Storage/FIRStorageUploadTask.m:73
```

I am able to upload images to Storage perfectly fine, and I am able to save the video to the phones camera roll perfectly.

Here is my code...

```
compressVideoWithOverlay(inputURL: videoURL, quality: AVAssetExportPreset640x480) { (exportSession) in
        guard let storyVideoUrl = exportSession?.outputURL else { return }

        let videoName = NSUUID().uuidString
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(uid).child("stories").child("\(videoName).mp4")

        storageRef.putFile(from: storyVideoUrl, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                self.stopActivityIndicatorWithMessage(completionMessage: R.string.stories.loadingMessageError())
                self.hideToolbar(hide: false)
                return
            }...
```

The error is returned on

```
storageRef.putFile(from: storyVideoUrl, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
```

I have also tried putData and get the same error.

compressVideoWithOverlay() returns a fileURL which seems to be working fine as I use that same URL to save to the camera roll.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, for anyone else that runs into this -  it's because I wasn't on the Main thread.

Comment: Thank you Dan!  You saved my life, buddy, I owe you one.

Comment: PS... shame on you Firebase devs... you could have given us a clue with that cryptic error message!